# How to change a property of a element on a Tap event, and revert it back when a different element is 'tapped'

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following use case. My page (`ContentView`), has several `CardView` elements. These CardViews are listed in a `WrapPanel` element (sort of list) and thus supplied by a `List<>` with items.

When the user clicks one of these CardViews, it's background color should change to mimic a 'Selected' status. The way I thought I could achieve this was by setting up a `TapGestureRecognizer` event on the CardView to catch the 'click', then on click I could change the background color.

This all worked fine, but when one CardView get's clicked the previous clicked CardView should revert back to normal, so the background color of the previous clicked CardView should revert back to the default value. So it should act like a `Radio Button` in a group.

To achieve the latter I thought I could 'store' the `x:Name` of the clicked element in C# to a property, and on a Tap event I would check if the property has a value and the value was different of the clicked element, if so then I would get the previous element by Name with `FindByName` and change the background color property back to default when found.

Though, after reading up on some other posts, I found out this is bad practice.

Any ideas how I can easily achieve these requirement? Perhaps with XAML alone? As a not so experienced Xamarin programmer this current solution was the only one which came to mind.

```
    <grial:WrapPanel
        Grid.Row="1"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentFloors}"
        VerticalOptions="Start">
        <grial:WrapPanel.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <grial:CardView
                    x:Name="{Binding DepartmentId}"
                    Margin="5,0,0,0"
                    Padding="7"
                    ClassId="{Binding DepartmentId}"
                    ColumnSpacing="6"
                    CornerRadius="16"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    RowSpacing="6">
                    
                    <!-- omitted other code / elements -->
                    <grial:CardView.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped" />
                    </grial:CardView.GestureRecognizers>
                </grial:CardView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </grial:WrapPanel.ItemTemplate>
    </grial:WrapPanel>
```

```
    private void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var clickedCardView = (CardView)sender;
        var floorID = clickedCardView.ClassId;
        clickedCardView.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
        if(floorID != PreviousCLickedFloor && PreviousCLickedFloor != null)
        {
            // Bad practice here..
            // omitted code to find previous element by name 
        }
        PreviousCLickedFloor = floorID;
        
    }
```

*** ***UPDATE*** ***

The WrapPanel is a element inside a Child page / ContentView. The ViewModel has 1 List<> property that fills the Child Page elements data, including the WrapPanel data.

**The parent page:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    ... >
    
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <Grid>
           
            <Grid>
                <!-- This carousel view contains all the elements / data (including the WrapPanel) -->
                <local:ExtendedCarouselView
                    x:Name="carousel"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                    IndicatorView="activityIndicatorView"
                    IsScrollAnimated="False"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ActivityData}"
                    Position="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <local:ExtendedCarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Frame Style="{StaticResource CarouselWorkaround}">
                                <local:PCSActivityOverviewTemplate />
                            </Frame>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </local:ExtendedCarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                </local:ExtendedCarouselView>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**The Child page**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
   ... >
   
    <ContentView.Content>

        <CarouselView
            x:Name="carousel"
            IsBounceEnabled="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource OneToManyConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}"
            Position="{Binding CurrentCarouselViewLocation}"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
            <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout
                    ItemSpacing="0"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    SnapPointsAlignment="Start"
                    SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" />
            </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>

            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <grial:IntMemberTemplateSelector MemberName="Position">
                    <grial:IntMemberTemplateSelector.Items>

                        <!--  CAROUSEL'S PAGE 0  -->
                        <grial:IntMemberTemplateSelectorItem Value="0">
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <!--  First element ignores BindingContext  -->
                                <Frame Style="{StaticResource CarouselWorkaround}">
                                    <Grid Margin="0,25,0,0" BindingContext="{Binding Value}">

                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="250" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="75" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        <Grid Margin="20">
                                        
                                            ... first (omitted) not so important element
                                          
                                        </Grid>

                                        <!-- Some other WrapPanel, which uses a different List<> binding --> 
                                        <grial:WrapPanel
                                            Grid.Row="1"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}"
                                            
                                            .... omitted the rest


                                        <!-- THE WrapPanel which need to change the style on click --> 
                                        <grial:WrapPanel
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentFloors}" <!-- the List with Floors --> 
                                            VerticalOptions="Start">
                                            <grial:WrapPanel.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <grial:CardView
                                                        x:Name="{Binding DepartmentId}"
                                                        Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                                        Padding="7"
                                                        ClassId="{Binding DepartmentId}"
                                                        ColumnSpacing="6"
                                                        CornerRadius="16"
                                                        HasShadow="True"
                                                        RowSpacing="6">
                                                        <grial:CardView.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                        </grial:CardView.RowDefinitions>

                                                        <grial:CardView.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
                                                        </grial:CardView.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                        <Label
                                                            Grid.Row="0"
                                                            Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                                            LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                                            Style="{StaticResource LabelBoldStyle}"
                                                            Text="{Binding DepartmentName, Converter={StaticResource ToUpperConverter}}"
                                                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

                                                        <!-- the TAP event -->
                                                        <grial:CardView.GestureRecognizers>
                                                            <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped" />
                                                        </grial:CardView.GestureRecognizers>

                                                       
                                                    </grial:CardView>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </grial:WrapPanel.ItemTemplate>
                                        </grial:WrapPanel>

   
                                    </Grid>
                                </Frame>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </grial:IntMemberTemplateSelectorItem>

                        <!--  CAROUSEL'S PAGE 1  -->
                        <grial:IntMemberTemplateSelectorItem Value="1">
                            <DataTemplate>
                            
                                ... the second view / page in the Carousel, omitted the elements in here
                                
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </grial:IntMemberTemplateSelectorItem>

                    </grial:IntMemberTemplateSelector.Items>
                </grial:IntMemberTemplateSelector>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

        </CarouselView>

    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**XAML of the ChildPage (which now contains the Tap event):**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class PCSActivityOverviewTemplate : ContentView
    {
        public string PreviousCLickedFloor;

       
        public PCSActivityOverviewTemplate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var clickedCardView = (CardView)sender;
            var floorID = clickedCardView.ClassId;
            clickedCardView.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;

            if(floorID != PreviousCLickedFloor && PreviousCLickedFloor != null)
            {
                ...
            }

            PreviousCLickedFloor = floorID;

        }

    }
```

**The ViewModel, which the Parent page uses:**

```
namespace PCS2.APP.ViewModels
{
    public class ActivityOverviewViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private List<ActivityLocation> activityData;
        private readonly IRoutingService _routingService;


        <! -- the List property that is being used as the Source of data -->
        public List<ActivityLocation> ActivityData
        {
            get { return activityData; }
            set { SetProperty(ref activityData, value); }
        }
        
        ... omitted some other properties

        public ActivityOverviewViewModel(int? clientId = null, IRoutingService routingService = null)
            : base(listenCultureChanges: true)
        {
            _routingService = routingService ?? Locator.Current.GetService<IRoutingService>();
            SelectItem = new Command(() => DoSelectItem());

            LoadData();
        }

        private async void LoadData()
        {
            try
            {
                // Getting the data and put it in the List property
                var _activitiesData = await App.Database.GetActivityDataAsync(_clientId, DateTime.UtcNow);
                ActivityData = _activitiesData;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
       
        }

    }
}
```

**The ActivityData Model**

```
namespace PCS2.APP.Models
{
    public class ActivityLocation 
    {
       
        public int ProjectId { get; set; } 
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; } 
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public string LocationImage { get; set; }
        public string LocationImageStatus { get; set; } = "resource://PCS2.APP.SharedImages.LocationBadge.svg";
        public int LocationTotalFloors { get; set; }
        public int LocationTotalRooms { get; set; }
        public int LocationTotalElements { get; set; }
        public List<ActivityTask> Tasks { get; set; }
        public ActivityTask CurrentTask { get; set; } 
        public List<ActivityFloor> CurrentFloors { get; set; } // The Floors that are being clicked and should change style
        public List<ActivityRoom> CurrentRooms { get; set; } 
    }

    public class ActivityTask
    {
        public int TaskId { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; } 
        public string TaskName { get; set; }
        public string TaskNameFull => $"Taak {TaskName}"; 
        public List<ActivityFloor> Floors { get; set; }
    }

    public class ActivityFloor
    {
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; } 
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; } 
        public int TaskId { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; } 
        public List<ActivityRoom> Rooms { get; set; }
    }

    public class ActivityRoom
    {
        public int RoomId { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; } 
        public int TaskId { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; } 
        public string RoomName { get; set; }
        public string FullRoomName { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string RoomDescription { get; set; }
        public int M2 { get; set; }
        public bool Finished { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd try MessagingCenter.  Every card can subscribe to a "Selected" message that passes a reference to the selected card.  All cards that receive the message should reset their bg color UNLESS they match the selected value.

Comment: I recommend not to abuse MessagingCenter for stuff like this. Move the behaviour into the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it clean I would put this behaviour into the ViewModel, that has `CurrentFloors`, then on each ViewModel for each of the cards, lets call it `FloorViewModel`, I would track the state of the item there. Whether it is selected or not through a `IsSelected` property.

Additionally, I would add a `SelectItem` command to the ViewModel with the list of `FloorViewModel` that takes a specific `FloorViewModel` to know which one was tapped.

In that command I would simply loop all the `FloorViewModel`s and appropriately set the `IsSelected` property of whether that specific item is selected.

This could look something like:

```
private void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var clickedCardView = (CardView)sender;
    ViewModel.SelectItem.Execute(clickedCardView.BindingContext);
}
```

In `FloorViewModel` add:

```
private bool _isSelected:
public bool IsSelected
{
    get => _isSelected;
    set => SetProperty(ref _isSelected, value);
}
```

In your `SelectItem` command:

```
public ICommand SelectItem { get; }

// in ctor of VM
SelectItem = new Command<FloorViewModel>(DoSelectItem);

private void DoSelectItem(FlooViewModel selectedItem)
{
    foreach(var floor in CurrentFloors)
    {
        floor.IsSelected = floor == selectedItem;
    }
}
```

Now you just need to set up some kind of style when `IsSelected` changes, this can be done in different ways. Such as binding the background color `IsSelected` and converting the bool with a `ValueConverter` to your desired color depending on whether the value is true or false.

Read more about commands in the Xamarin.Forms docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding

Comment: or also binding `IsSelected ` in a style trigger

Comment: @Cheesebaron The problem is that my ViewModel looks quite different. The 'Floors' is a list property contained in another property. The ViewModel tha tis being used lies on top of the WrapPanel (which is in a ContentView). So the data is set upo as following: List of locations --> 1 location --> has multiple floors. How would I do it with this setup? I added / updated my ViewModel and setup in the main post.

Comment: Don't display DTO's directly use ViewModels